# Test ad(Interstitial) always shows but not another, why?

Tags: android-studio, interstitial

```
//**i have this in my onCreate**//
    mInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(<my another 
    ad_unit_id>));
    mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
@Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            mInterstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
            Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial Ad = onAdClosed()");
        }
mInterstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    displayInterstitial();
    Log.d(TAG,"APP = onBackPressed()");
}
 protected void displayInterstitial() {
    Log.d(TAG, "start displayInterstitial()");
    if (null!=mInterstitial&&mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "displayInterstitial() loaded");
        mInterstitial.show();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "end displayInterstitial()");
}
```

when i put test add(interstitial) it appears after backpress_ but another interstitial ad could not load.

Answer (score 0):

I think your wi-fi connection is poor.